# Parameter Variation: Get dataset for one specific iteration

Tags: anylogic

I run a parameter variation experiment in Anylogic and collect histogram data about the number of specific agents. This histogram returns the min, mean, and max-value (among others).

I am looking for a way to get the dataset for one specific iteration only (the iteration that is closest to the mean-value of the histogram data).

Is there a way to return data for one specific iteration?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not with HistogramData objects.

Use normal `Dataset` objects in your experiment. In the properties, you can switch to "use x value as iteration" and store any value from your model iterations in the y-value.

Now you have a nice table with data from your individual iterations.

cheers

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, one step closer to the solution! 
Now that I know the iteration I am interested in, can I add data from this specific iteration to another dataset? Maybe something like dataset2.add(get.iteration(X).Data?
I could not find a related command in the documentation.

Comment: Use `DataSet.getY(i)` where i is the iteration number you are interested in. Add it to another dataset using `add(x,y)`